# What is the probability that x is less than 5.92?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, means, variance

Let x follow a Normal distribution with mean 2 and variance 4.
This question is not a duplicate. One question is stating between two variables

Basic stats question having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: do you know the cumulative distribution function of normal distribution?

Comment: @Guangliang  No,I am unfamiliar on how to get to that answer from using it

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the probability that $x$ is between $-1.92$ and $5.92$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162864/what-is-the-probability-that-x-is-between-1-92-and-5-92)

Comment: @pjs36 how if one is stating between two variables and the other just numbers before?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$Pr(X < 5.92) = Pr\left(\frac{X-2}{2} < \frac{5.92-2}{2}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{X-2}{2} \sim N(0,1)$$

Edit:

Such values are usually found by using statistical tables (e.g. http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf  [Credit:JMoravitz] )

$$\frac{5.92-2}{2}=1.96$$

Reading from the table, $F_Z(1.96) = 0.975 $ which is the value that you want to find.

Remark: $1.96$ is a "special" value as it is commonly used in constructing $95\%$ confidence interval.

Comment: What would be the X in this case then?

Comment: X is just a random variable

Comment: @user29418 Im unsure where to go with this

Comment: Lets call $\frac{X-2}{2}$ something else, $Z$.  We have that $Z$ is the standard normal distribution with mean zero and standard deviation $1$.  The value of $Pr(Z<\frac{5.92-2}{2})$ can be found with calculus, or you can simply look up the value (*or at least a nearby value*) on a table such as [this one](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf).  Any textbook with any reference to a normal curve will include such a table somewhere, often in the appendix.