# What is the probability that $x$ is between $-1.92$ and $5.92$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let x follow a Normal distribution with mean $2$ and variance $4$.

Stats question that I need help on.

Comment: You have to reduce this to a Normal(0,1) and then tabulate

Comment: Take this one step at a time.  What is the probability that $x$ is less than $-1.92$?  How many standard deviations below the mean is $-1.92$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162732/what-is-the-probability-that-x-is-less-than-5-92?rq=1

Comment: @BruceET what are you talking about... just giving the final answer wouldn't be helpful to help the person *learn* how to do this on his own in the first place, but giving an arbitrary number (*which is incorrect*) is not helpful either.  Did you forget that he said variance and not standard deviation?

Comment: @JMoravitz What formula should be first used to find out the probability of x?

Comment: @JMoravitz: Sorry, typo. Just returned to fix it. Answer is about .95. Removing previous Comment.

Comment: @Thedonwon look at your previous question and the already existing answer and the comments on that answer.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize the values in order to use the standard Normal distribution (whose values are usually given in a table in a statistics course).

\begin{align}
z_1 &= \frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma} & z_2 &= \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma} \\
 &= \frac{-1.92-2}{2} &  &= \frac{5.92-2}{2} \\
&= -1.96 &  &= 1.96 \\
\end{align}

Recall that the Normal distribution is symmetric around the mean.

Let $Z$ be a standard uniformly distributed variable.
\begin{align}
P(-1.96 \leq Z \leq 1.96) &= P(|Z| \leq 1.96) \\
&= 1 - P(|Z| > 1.96) \\
&= 1 - 2 \cdot P(Z < -1.96) \\
&= 1 - 2 \cdot P(Z < -1.96) \\
&\approx 1 - 2 \dot (0.025) \\
&\approx 1 - 0.05 \\
&\approx 0.95
\end{align}

Comment: And now we just have to wait for installment number 3 of the same question by this OP... Pity.